# Google Drive grabs all symlink'd files when uploading

Tags: symbolic-link, google-drive

I'm trying to upload a folder (in which are several symlinks to hefty PDF files) to Google Drive. It's 60 MB not counting the symlinked files, and about 300 MB counting them.

Google Drive insists that the folder is 300 MB -- I suspect it's trying to upload all the symlinked files. How do I get it to stop doing this and ignore the symlinks?

Comment: Which of many upload methods are you using ?

Comment: That is the purpose of symlinks. You would need a tool that lets you treat them as ordinary files or that lets you exclude them. A Backup tool such as SyncbackSE Pro.

Comment: I'm doing `New --> Folder Upload` and selecting the desired folder.